# Kindly explain clearly the CTE Query?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I saw

```
WITH tblTemp as
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() Over(PARTITION BY Name,Department ORDER BY Name) As RowNumber, * 
   FROM <table_name>
)
DELETE FROM tblTemp where RowNumber > 1
```

This query for deleting duplicate rows, but I can't understand the Query. Could you please explain clearly?

Comment: What part exactly don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

The `common table expression` is locating duplicate rows, then the delete query that follows removes all but one row if there are duplicates.

```
SELECT
   ROW_NUMBER() Over(PARTITION BY Name,Department ORDER BY Name) As RowNumber
   ,* 
FROM <table_name>
```

In the `over()` clause the `partition` and `order by` defines where numbering starts at 1, then within each `partition` each extra row gets a larger row number. Hence when `[RowNumber] = 1` you have a unique set of rows for name and department.

see: [Over()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [row_number()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

[Demonstration](http://rextester.com/FJYB90948)

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   name       VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
  ,department VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(name,department) VALUES ('fred','sales');
INSERT INTO mytable(name,department) VALUES ('fred','sales');
INSERT INTO mytable(name,department) VALUES ('barney','admin');
INSERT INTO mytable(name,department) VALUES ('barney','admin');
INSERT INTO mytable(name,department) VALUES ('wilma','engineering');



WITH tblTemp as
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() Over(PARTITION BY Name,Department ORDER BY Name) As RowNumber, * 
   FROM mytable
)
DELETE FROM tblTemp where RowNumber > 1
;

select
*
from mytable
;

+---+--------+-------------+
|   |  name  | department  |
+---+--------+-------------+
| 1 | fred   | sales       |
| 2 | barney | admin       |
| 3 | wilma  | engineering |
+---+--------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The most instructive thing for you to do would be to select from the CTE:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblTemp
ORDER BY Department, Name;
```

Off the top of my head, you might see a result set looking like this:

```
Name          | Department | RowNumber
Jon Skeet     | Software   | 1
Gordon Linoff | Database   | 1
Gordon Linoff | Database   | 2
```

The `(Gordon Linoff, Database)` record appears in duplicate, so there is a row number value in the second record which is greater than 1.  Your delete logic would remove this duplicate, but would not affect the `(Jon Skeet, Software)` record, which has no duplicate.